# com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata-api

I had working code till yesterday and today i am seeing exception `com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException`  while reading google doc from my gae code as follows. Please note that the last line is throwing this exception.

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("sakshum-YourAppName-v1");
            client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters,
                    new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
            URL feedUrl = new URL(
                    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
            DocumentQuery dquery = new DocumentQuery(feedUrl);
            dquery.setTitleQuery(title);
            dquery.setTitleExact(true);
            dquery.setMaxResults(10);
            DocumentListFeed resultFeed = client.getFeed(dquery,
                    DocumentListFeed.class);
            log.info("feed size:" + resultFeed.getEntries().size());
            if (resultFeed.getEntries().size() != 1) {
                log.info("More than one document is found with same title.");
                return null;
            }
            emailBody = new StringBuffer("");
            for (DocumentListEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
                String docId = entry.getDocId();
                String docType = entry.getType();
                log.info("Getting doc from url with docId:" + docId
                        + " docType:" + docType);
                URL exportUrl = new URL(
                        "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/" + docType
                                + "s/Export?docID=" + docId
                                + "&exportFormat=html");
                MediaContent mc = new MediaContent();
                mc.setUri(exportUrl.toString());
            log.info("Getting media");
            MediaSource ms = client.getMedia(mc);
```

Detailed Stack Trace:

```
vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode getGoogleDoc: com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: OK
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, spreadsheets and presentations"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/common/drive_favicon1.ico"><title>Google Drive -- Page Not Found</title><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><style>/* Copyright 2013 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */
.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{color:#91959c;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;font-size:27px;font-weight:300;position:absolute;text-shadow:0 1px 1px white;white-space:nowrap}#drive-logo img{padding:0 0.4em 0 0;position:relative;top:2px;vertical-align:middle}#drive-logo a{color:#91959c;text-decoration:none}#drive-logo span.goog-inline-block{margin-top:2px;vertical-align:top}</style><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a: link, a: visited {color: #112ABB;}</style><style type="text/css">.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}</style></head><body><div style="margin: auto; max-width: 750px;"><div style="margin: 80px 40px 20px 40px; position:relative; "><div style="position: absolute; top: -80px;"><h1 id="drive-logo"><a href="/"><img src="//www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" width="116" height="41" alt="Google logo" ><span class="goog-inline-block">Drive</span></a></h1></div><div align="center"><p class="errorMessage" style="padding-top: 50px">Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.</p><p>Make sure that you have the correct URL and that the owner of the file hasn&#39;t deleted it.</p><div style="background: #F0F6FF; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 35px; padding: 10px 125px; width: 300px;"><p><strong>Get stuff done with Google Drive</strong></p><p>Apps in Google Drive make it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets, presentations and more.</p><p>Learn more at <a href="https://drive.google.com/start/apps">drive.google.com/start/apps</a>.</p></div></div></div></div></body></html>

at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:591)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource(MediaService.java:234)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:276)
at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMedia(MediaService.java:302)
at vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode.getGoogleDoc(CommonServiceCode.java:920)
at vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.PocServiceImpl.activatePOCs(PocServiceImpl.java:1807)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:179)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:176)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:137)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:45)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.doFilter(AppstatsFilter.java:141)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: detailed logs print as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issues are because of the deprecated google APIs. I am moving to google drive api.

Comment: IS ResourceNotFoundException exception fixed after using "google drive api"? If yes then please send me "google drive api" link.

Comment: I got list of folders (in google docs) from api. Is there any way to differentiate from the list of folders, which folder is folder (root folder) and which is subfolder (folder in root folder)?
I have found only one thing from api which returns the name of folder nothing more (is this folder is subfolder or not).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the resource you are trying to download according to the URL you are building is no longer there.  It might be either:

1. You deleted the file.
2. The URL format used to find the file has changed.

Comment: well it started coming for all the docs we have. So not possible that all the docs are deleted. how to find for the 2nd possibility?

Comment: Well, the HTML error its outputting is definitely saying that the file you tried to retrieve isn't there, or that the URL is wrong.

Try this. That 'docType' variable you have, hardcode it to be 'document' always, instead of based on the entry type.

Comment: Or rather, look at your log.  Do the types match what you are expecting?  Also, for debugging purposes, I recommend you take that URL, set it to a variable, print it to your log and see if it looks how you expect it to look. Also log the exportUrl.toString() and make sure it looks as expected.